# Calling an ActionResult of Controller in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, model-view-controller

I am trying to call an ActionResult inside the Controller in javascript.

I have this ActionResult in my `AdminController`.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Logout()
{
    return RedirectToAction("Login", "Login");
}
```

This is my `Logout button` in AdminView.

```
<a class="navbar-link" id="logout" name="logout" href="#">
    ログアウト
</a>
```

And try to create an event in JAVSCRIPT.

```
  $("#logout").click(function () {
        swal({
            title: "ログアウト?",
            text: "アカウントからサインアウトしますか？",
            icon: "warning",
            buttons: true,
            dangerMode: true,
        })
            .then((willLogout) => {
                if (willLogout) {
                    //swal("Poof! Your imaginary file has been deleted!", {
                    //    icon: "success",
                    //});
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/Admin/Logout",
                        type: 'POST',
                        success: function (result) {
                            document.location.reload(true);
                        }, 
                        error: function (result) {

                        }
                    });
                }
            });
    });
```

The main purpose of this is to redirect the user to Login Page using the Controller.

I tried setting the `swal("Poof")...` inside the `.then(willLogout)` and it works.

but when I use an ajax to call the ActionResult. It did not work.

I saw the console and seems nothing is displayed.

I don't know what am I doing wrong.

How can I call the `ActionResult` from Controller to the Javascript file with `Ajax` call?

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: @HugoElhaj-Lahsen ASP.NET MVC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to help my fellow beginners. This is the solution I coped up.

First of all, I learned that each ActionResult should have a View (If I am not mistaken).

So, In my `AdminView.cshtml`, I create a hidden button.

```
  <button type="submit" id="submitLogout" name="button" value="logout" hidden>logout</button>
```

After that, In my `JSFILE`

I removed the ajax. which is in the first place is wrong.

```
   $("#logout").click(function () {
        swal({
            title: "ログアウト?",
            text: "アカウントからサインアウトしますか？",
            icon: "warning",
            buttons: true,
            dangerMode: true,
        })
            .then((willLogout) => {
                if (willLogout) {
                    $("#submitLogout").click();
                }
            });
    });
```

This function in javascript is to trigger the hidden button in `.cshtml` and trigger the `ActionResult` in the Controller.

Also, In my Controller. This is what I said that each `ActionResult` has to have a View.

```
 public ActionResult AdminView(string button)
    {
        if (button == "logout")
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            Session.RemoveAll();
            Session.Abandon();
            return RedirectToActionPermanent("Login", "Login");
        }
        else
        {
            if (!(Session["UserInfo"] is UserModel))
            {
                return RedirectToActionPermanent("Login", "Login");
            }
            else
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
    }
```

The parameter `string button` in the ActionResult is the `name of the button` which you want to trigger. If the trigger is successful, it will pass the value of the button to the argument `string button`.